# How to splitt a Linq-Function?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, visual-studio-2012

I've got a Linq-Function, which partialy gets used in different methods, so I thought it would be possible to split it in different parts, which I might call, when I need them:

```
    public static void SetTab(int tab)
    {
        var collection = from product in Entity.Collection.collection
                         let p = product as Entity.Base.Product
                         from version in p.version
                         let v = version as Entity.Base.Version
                         from customer in v.customerCollection
                         let c = customer as Entity.Base.Customer
                         from error in v.errorCollection
                         let e = error as Entity.Base.Error
                         select new { p, v, c, e };

        Entity.Selection.products = (List<Entity.Base.Product>)collection.Select(x => x.p).Distinct().ToList();
            Entity.Selection.versions = (List<Entity.Base.Version>)collection.Select(x => x.v).Distinct().ToList();
                Entity.Selection.customers = (List<Entity.Base.Customer>)collection.Select(x => x.c).Distinct().ToList();
                Entity.Selection.errors = (List<Entity.Base.Error>)collection.Select(x => x.e).Distinct().ToList();
                    Entity.Selection.categories = (List<Entity.Base.Category>)collection.Select(x => x.e.category).Distinct().ToList();

        switch (tab)
        {
            case 0:
                Entity.DataSource.MainTab.lbProduct = Converter.ListConverter.ToBindingList(Entity.Selection.products);
                    Entity.DataSource.MainTab.lbVersion = Converter.ListConverter.ToBindingList(Entity.Selection.versions);
                        Entity.DataSource.MainTab.lbCustomer = Converter.ListConverter.ToBindingList(Entity.Selection.customers);
                        Entity.DataSource.MainTab.lbError = Converter.ListConverter.ToBindingList(Entity.Selection.errors);
                            Entity.DataSource.MainTab.lbCategory = Converter.ListConverter.CategoryToBindingList(Entity.Selection.categories);
                break;
        }
    }
```

this should look something like this:

```
    private static object GetFrom()
    {
        var collection = from product in Entity.Collection.collection
                         let p = product as Entity.Base.Product
                         from version in p.version
                         let v = version as Entity.Base.Version
                         from customer in v.customerCollection
                         let c = customer as Entity.Base.Customer
                         from error in v.errorCollection
                         let e = error as Entity.Base.Error
                         select new { p, v, c, e };
    }

    public static void SetTab(int tab)
    {
        Reduce(GetFrom());
        SelectThis(0);
    }

    private static void Reduce(object collection)
    {
        Entity.Selection.products = (List<Entity.Base.Product>)collection.Select(x => x.p).Distinct().ToList();
            Entity.Selection.versions = (List<Entity.Base.Version>)collection.Select(x => x.v).Distinct().ToList();
                Entity.Selection.customers = (List<Entity.Base.Customer>)collection.Select(x => x.c).Distinct().ToList();
                Entity.Selection.errors = (List<Entity.Base.Error>)collection.Select(x => x.e).Distinct().ToList();
                    Entity.Selection.categories = (List<Entity.Base.Category>)collection.Select(x => x.e.category).Distinct().ToList();
    }

    private static void SelectThis(int i)
    {
        switch (tab)
        {
            case 0:
                Entity.DataSource.MainTab.lbProduct = Converter.ListConverter.ToBindingList(Entity.Selection.products);
                    Entity.DataSource.MainTab.lbVersion = Converter.ListConverter.ToBindingList(Entity.Selection.versions);
                        Entity.DataSource.MainTab.lbCustomer = Converter.ListConverter.ToBindingList(Entity.Selection.customers);
                        Entity.DataSource.MainTab.lbError = Converter.ListConverter.ToBindingList(Entity.Selection.errors);
                            Entity.DataSource.MainTab.lbCategory = Converter.ListConverter.CategoryToBindingList(Entity.Selection.categories);
                break;
        }
    }
```

My question is: what do i need to use, instead of "object" to pass "var collection" from one method to another?

Comment: Why are you executing a DB query 5 different times just to get a list of each of the 5 properties of a given object?  You can just execute the query once and pull all of the data down instead.  On top of that, you're performing a cross join between 5 different tables just so that you can pull out all of the individual distinct values.  That's *super* wasteful of DB resources.  Why not just pull down each list, instead of combining each list with 4 others just to ignore all of those other values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an explicit class which is equivalent to the anonymous class that is now defined on the fly as part of the query. **And** I strongly suggest that you call `ToList()` on the query, because this makes sure the query is executed only once.

```
public class MyClass
{
    Entity.Base.Product Product { get; private set; }
    Entity.Base.Version Version { get; private set; }
    Entity.Base.Customer Customer { get; private set; }
    Entity.Base.Error Error { get; private set; }

    public MyClass(
                Entity.Base.Product product,
                Entity.Base.Version version,
                Entity.Base.Customer customer,
                Entity.Base.Error error)
    {
        this.Product = product;
        this.Version = version;
        this.Customer = customer;
        this.Error = error;
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
private static List<MyClass> GetFrom()
{
    return (from product in Entity.Collection.collection
            let p = product as Entity.Base.Product
            from version in p.version
            let v = version as Entity.Base.Version
            from customer in v.customerCollection
            let c = customer as Entity.Base.Customer
            from error in v.errorCollection
            let e = error as Entity.Base.Error
            select new MyClass(p, v, c, e)
           ).ToList();
}
```